# template неправильно работает

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

// header.hpp

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> class A
{
   T1 a;
   T2 b;
public:
   A(void);
};
```

//header.cpp

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> A<T1, T2>::A(void)
{
   ...
}
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "header.hpp"

int main(void)
{
   A<double, double> a;
   return 0;
}
```

// errors : undefined reference to `A<double, double>::A(void)`
Я что-то неправильно написал. Но что самое страшное: когда я помещаю это все в один файл, внимание, все работает!
компилирование:

```
 1 all: prog
  2 
  3 prog: header.o main.o
  4         g++ header.o main.o -g -o prog
  5 main.o: main.cpp
  6         g++ main.cpp -c -g -o main.o
  7 header.o: header.cpp header.hpp
  8         g++ header.cpp -c -g -o header.o
  9 clean:
 10         rm *.o
 11         rm prog
```

Comment: обновление. Если в main.cpp написать: A<double, double> a(); то все заработает.

Comment: `A<double, double> a();` - это **объявление** функции `a`, не принимающей аргументов и возвращающей `A<double, double>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда дело имеете с шаблонами, тогда в файл, где находится точка входа, необходимо подключать файл с расширением .сpp, где реализован ваш шаблонный класс.

Comment: Ок, тогда мне интересно, как при компиляции обрабатываются шаблоны, что возникают такие неудобства....

Comment: @GeorgeKasparyants, в какой среде разработке пишете?

Answer (score 2):

Не выносите реализации шаблонов в отдельные файлы!
Это может сработать, но в особых, редких ситуациях.

Весь код шаблона располагайте в заголовочном файле, и будет вам счастье :)

Comment: Ок, тогда мне интересно, как при компиляции обрабатываются шаблоны, что возникают такие неудобства....

Comment: Так и отрабатываются - когда выясняется, с каким типом работать, берется текст и подставляется. Чтобы реализация была совсем отдельно и прилинковывалась - нужно, чтоб там был сгенерированный код для конкретного вашего типа. Как его генерировать компилятору? Заранее для всех возможных типов? Просто поставьте себя на место компилятора и попробуйте прикинуть. Ведь реализация шаблонного класса/функции не компилируется, пока не станет известно, для какого типа ее следует компилировать.